# Autofac intergration with Owin/WebApi failing with parameterless constructor

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, autofac

I have setup an mvc5.2 webapi project and have added all of the dependencies for autofac and owin.

Within my startup class I have the following code which is taken directly from the docs [Autofac Owin Doco](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html#owin-integration)

The only change I have made is `RegisterApiTypes(builder);`

```
  public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        RegisterApiTypes(builder);

        // STANDARD WEB API SETUP:

        // Get your HttpConfiguration. In OWIN, you'll create one
        // rather than using GlobalConfiguration.
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        // Register your Web API controllers.
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

        // Run other optional steps, like registering filters,
        // per-controller-type services, etc., then set the dependency resolver
        // to be Autofac.
        var container = builder.Build();
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

        // OWIN WEB API SETUP:

        // Register the Autofac middleware FIRST, then the Autofac Web API middleware,
        // and finally the standard Web API middleware.
        app.UseAutofacMiddleware(container);
        app.UseAutofacWebApi(config);
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }

    private static void RegisterApiTypes(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<Logger>()
           .As<ILogger>()
           .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<EmailService>()
            .As<IEmailService>()
            .InstancePerRequest();
    }


}
```

The startup class is called and there isn't any issues however when I try hit a controller I get the

> An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'MyController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.

Should I be setting up the Startup.cs differently?

Comment: Do your `EmailService` and `Logger` both have parameterless constructors?

Comment: Can you show us the constructor for `MyController`?